# Finding directional derivative given direction and point

Tags: derivatives

Let $f(x,y,z) = x^2 -2y + 3z^2$

I need to find the direction derivative of f at $(0,1,0)$ in the direction $v=[1,1,1]$.

The formula given is

```
f(a + tv) - f(a) / t|v| = f( (0,1,0) + t[1,1,1] ) - f(a) / tv
                        = f(t, 1+t, t) - f(0,1,0) / tv
```

I'm not sure how `(0,1,0) + t[1,1,1] = t, 1+t, t`? If expanded, we get `(0,1,0) + [t,t,t]`. How was this part done (since it is a point + a vector)? Is it just [0 + t, 1 + t, 0 + t]?

Comment: Yes, it is just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $f(x,y)=x^2-2y+3z^2$

The unit vector in the direction of $\vec v=\dfrac{\vec v}{||\vec v||}=\left<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right>$

The partial derivatives are $$f_x=2x,f_y=-2,f_z=6z$$
$$f_x(0,1,0)=0,f_y(0,1,0)=-2,f_z(0,1,0)=0$$

Then the directional derivative is$$D_{\vec u}f(0,1,0)=0\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-2\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+0\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$$